# use parts of ajax results after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple upload form that sends the request via ajax post. The result (data) is shown in a bootstrap modal - works like intended.

Parts of the upload.php are reading exif data from the uploaded image and I'd like to use these information on my start form (updating placeholders with exif info).

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#uploadForm', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: './includes/upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success:  function(data){
                $('#modal .modal-body').html(data);
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            }
       });
    });
```

html result:

```
        <img src="<?php echo $imgpPath; ?>" />
        <div class='fp_upload'>
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                <?php
                    echo '<p class="body">'.$img_body.'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="lens">'.$img_lens.'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="iso">'.$img_iso.'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="aperture">'.$img_aperture.'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="exposure">'.$img_exposure.'</p>';
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What would be a good way to get the desired infos somewhere in data?

Greeings Fabio

Comment: The HTML will be returned in `data` and you should be able to parse that. You may find it easier to return JSON.

Comment: dont't return HTML from a ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I know, with JSON it would get easier, but I found a way to find specific values in my data and place them in inputs.

My submit code is untouched, inside the success I added.

```
var img_name = $(data).find('#img_name').attr('data-placeholder');
$('#input_name').val(img_name);
```

Greetings Fabio